# Which is the best protocol for REST APIs manipulating list of strings?

Tags: rest, http, web

From http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

> A REST API should not be dependent on any single communication protocol, though its successful mapping to a given protocol may be dependent on the availability of metadata, choice of methods, etc. In general, any protocol element that uses a URI for identification must allow any URI scheme to be used for the sake of that identification.

What I have understood is that we can use HTTP, FTP, Gopher anything for REST. Because all of them are URI driven.

The protocols are designed for specific purpose. Some are good for binary data some are good for text. In my case, the APIs will manipulate string lists. I want to understand that which protocol should be used to manipulate list of strings.

Use Case:

A set of APIs to manage list of items to purchase.

GET /my_purchase_list/1 # to fetch list number 1

GET /my_purchase_list/2 # to fetch list number 2

GET /my_purchase_list/1/item/5 # to fetch item 5 from list 1

PUT /my_purchase_list/1 # update a list

POST /my_purchase_list # to add an item to the list

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulate list of strings"? Can you modify the question to show a real use case? E.g. action + URL input leading to expected output?

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. I have added an example use case to make it clearer.

Comment: We usually use REST with HTTP. I don't know of a protocol specially designed to the string manipulation you want to do. In your use case you used the HTTP protocol as well, so I guess you want to do this task with it. So what is the question?

Comment: HTTP is the default choice. But are there any other protocols which work better for this task?

Comment: If all you need is CRUD, I don't think there is a better protocol for that.

Comment: OK, so that works. But how is that string manipulation? What you do under the covers of the API is your business, but that is classic REST right there

Comment: Sorry again. To be precise it should be list manipulation.